# Question about graphing piecewise functions in r

Tags: r, function, statistics

The question asks, if f(x) = exp(−|x|)/2, −∞ < x < ∞.

Derive the quantile function F inverse
(p) and graph it from 0.01 to 0.99.

So, I computed F inverse p and tried to graph the curve using the code

```
QF<-function(p){
  if (0<p&p<=0.5){
    log(2*p)}
  else if (0.5<p&p<1){
    -log(2*(1-p))}
}
curve(QF, from=0.01, to=0.99, , xlab="x", ylab="f(x)")
```

But the curve does not look the way it should. Its only graphing the first part of the function log(2p) and not the second condition.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In R, an `if` statement can only respond to a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`. The expression `0 < p & p <= 0.5` inside your `if` statement evaluates to a *vector* of `TRUE` and `FALSE` the same length as the numeric *vector* `p`. The `if` statement defaults to using the first element of the vector but emits the warning

```
#> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Since the `curve` function has to find hundreds of y values, it passes a *vector* of x values to the function `QF`, starting at `from = 0.01`. The first number in this vector will therefore be between 0 and 0.5, triggering the `if` statement to branch to the `log(2*p)` expression *for all of `p`*.

Instead, you need to use the vectorized function `ifelse`, which will calculate both branches appropriately and return a single vector for `curve` to use as y co-ordinates.

```r
QF <- function(p){
  f_x <- ifelse(test = p <= 0.5, 
                yes  = log(2*p),
                no   = -log(2*(1-p)))
  
  # Remove values outside the range [0, 1]
  f_x[p < 0 | p > 1] <- NA
  
  return(f_x)
}

curve(QF, from = 0.01, to = 0.99, xlab = "x", ylab = "f(x)")
```

[image]

An alternative is to directly write the subsets to the result vector:

```r
QF <- function(p){

  f_x <- numeric(length(p))
  f_x[p <  0.5] <-  log(2 * p[p < 0.5])
  f_x[p >= 0.5] <- -log(2 * (1 - p[p >= 0.5]))
  f_x[p <  0.0] <- NA
  f_x[p >  1.0] <- NA
  
  return(f_x)
}
```

Which gives the same result.

<sup>Created on 2021-11-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>